# Make the variable not overwrite to null and check if the codes are correct

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I have created a class which is based on the question from this exercise.

I've tried my best to follow it and I think the reason why my variables are 0 or null is that I didn't write anything in the constructor. The question didn't say anything about what to write in the constructor.

I'm printing everything out because I want to see the result, but all I get from getCardNumber is null, getBalance is 0, coffee is 0. redeemFreeCoffee and isFreeCoffeeAvailable does work, simply because there are no variables that override them.

Here's the full question:

> **a.** Each loyalty card stores the card number, current balance (the number of points) and the number of coffees on the card. Implement a
>   constructor with the card number (of type String) as its argument and
>   method getCardNumber() and getBalance().
>
> **b.** Implement a method collectRewards(double amount, int coffees) that takes the amount spent (in pounds) and the number of coffees
>   bought and increases the balance (by one point for every pound spent)
>   as well as the number of coffees on the card.
>
> **c.** Implement a method isFreeCoffeeAvailable() that checks whether a free coffee is available, that is, whether the number of coffees on
>   the card is greater than or equal to 9.
>
> **d.** Implement a method redeemFreeCoffee() that first checks whether a free coffee is available. If this is the case then it reduces the
>   number of coffees by 9 and returns true, otherwise false.

I've tried changing the variables from private to public but I still get the same result.

I've even tried putting my main in a different class but the result is still the same.

```
public String cardNumber;
public int balance;
public int coffee;
public double amount; 

public String getCardNumber () {
    return cardNumber;
}

public int getBalance () {
    return balance;
}

public double collectRewards(double amount, int coffees) {
    if (amount > 0) { 
        coffee++;
        balance++;
    }
    return amount;
}

public int isFreeCoffeeAvailable(){
    if (coffee >= 9) {
        return coffee; 
    }
    return coffee;
}

public boolean redeemFreeCoffee() {
    if (coffee > 9) {
        coffee-=9;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }   
}

public LoyaltyCard (String cardNumber){

}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    String cardNumber = "0987654321";
    LoyaltyCard LoyaltyCardOne = new LoyaltyCard(cardNumber);
    System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s",LoyaltyCardOne.getCardNumber(),LoyaltyCardOne.getBalance(),LoyaltyCardOne.collectRewards(6.0,5),LoyaltyCardOne.redeemFreeCoffee(),LoyaltyCardOne.isFreeCoffeeAvailable()); 
}
```

I'd like to see the result for getCardNumber(), getBalance() and the amount of coffee.

Answer (score 1):

> all I get from getCardNumber is null

You never initialized it

```
public LoyaltyCard (String cardNumber){
   this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
}
```

> because there are no variables that override them.

I think you might be confused about what "override" means, but that isn't the problem.

> getBalance is 0, coffee is 0

You're calling those before you ever "collect rewards"

You will need to collect before printing the invidiual values, and read the logic again - increase by one point **for every pound spent**. So, focus on changing this block to fix that.

```
if (amount > 0) {
  coffee++;
  balance++;
}
```

Note that the instructions don't say the collectRewards returns anything. Also `coffee` should be increased by the input parameter, maybe than just 1.

Otherwise, you would need to call collectRewards at least 9 times before the redeem and isAvailable methods would work.

And once those are, you could do this, rather than rewrite `coffee > 9`

```
if (this.isFreeCoffeeAvailable()) {

} else {

}
```

Note: `isFreeCoffeeAvailable` should probably `return coffee > 9;` rather than return the amount

Answer (score 0):

In Java all non-local variables are initialized to 0, or null. So far in the code you don't set variables to your desired values. You can either create a constructor which takes values, e,g:

```
 LoyaltyCard(int balance, int coffee, double amount) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.coffee = coffee;
        // ... and other fields
```

or create setters for each field:

```
public setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
```